# Is there a way to extract a primary decomposition of $(0)\subset R/I$ given a decomposition of $I\subset R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, primary-decomposition

Suppose we have a (minimal) primary decomposition of an ideal $I$ in a polynomial ring $R$ over a field; for simplicity assume $I=I_1\cap I_2$ where $I_j$ is $P_j$-primary. Is there a way to extract from this a primary decomposition of $(0)$ in $R/I$? If so, say $(0)=J_1\cap\dots\cap J_k$ where $J_i$ is $Q_i$-primary.

Can I just take the equality $I=I_1\cap I_2$ and replace all generators by their residues mod $I$? If so, how to justify this? How are $Q_i$ and $P_j$ related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three results that together solve your problem:

1. For $I\subset R$ an ideal, there's a bijective correspondence between ideals of $R$ containing $I$ and ideals in $R/I$, given by sending $J\supset I \mapsto J/I$. (Correspondence theorem)
2. If $I\subset J$ are ideals in $R$, then $(R/I)/(I/J)\cong R/J$, and the maps are the obvious maps. (Third isomorphism theorem)
3. An ideal $I\subset R$ is primary iff the only zero divisors of $R/I$ are nilpotent. (Definition of primary ideal)

So the images of the ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$ in $R/I$ are still primary, since $R/I_i \cong (R/I)/(I_i/I)$ and thus the condition on zero divisors being nilpotent is still satisfied. Further, any primary decomposition of $(0)\subset R/I$ gives rise bijectively to a primary decomposition of $I\subset R$ and vice-versa via 1. In short, your final line about "[replacing] all generators by their residue mod $I$" is correct.

Comment: So in particular, my terminology, $P_k=Q_k$ for $k=1,2$ by the third isomorphism theorem? (And $J_k=I_k/I$)

Comment: Assuming I've read your post right (it's a little tough in places), $P_k$ cannot equal $Q_k$ since they're ideals of different rings.

Comment: But in both cases we are dealing with primary decompositions of $R$-modules (in the first case the module is $I\subset R$, in the second case it's $0\subset R/I$). Shouldn't the components of either decomposition be $P$-primary ideals for some prime ideal $P\subset R$? I thought such $P$s live in one and the same ring $R$.

Comment: In my experience, it is typical that when one writes about primary decompositions of ideals in rings, one means the primary decomposition of that ideal in that ring. If you mean something else, you should say that specifically.